# Mapping Over an Array and Converting Date Property to Milliseconds and Returning New Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to iterate over an array of objects, convert the date property to milliseconds, and then end up with a new array, with the same properties as the first array, but with the date property changed to milliseconds.

So for this:

```
let records = [
  {id: 1, date: '29/06/2020'},
  {id: 2, date: '29/07/2020'},
  {id: 3, date: '29/08/2020'}
]
```

I should end up with:

```
[
  {id: 1, date: 1593403200000}
  {id: 2, date: 1595995200000}
  {id: 3, date: 1598673600000}
]
```

I was using map like so:

```
 let newRecords = records.map(r => r.date = moment(r.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').valueOf());
```

... but it returns an array of objects containing ONLY the date property, like so:

```
[
  1593403200000, 
  1595995200000, 
  1598673600000
]
```

... whereas I want the original objects, just with the date converted to milliseconds. How can I edit my `map()` function to return the entire original object in the new array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will return a new array of values you return from the callback function. So in your case you should return the object and not the date value.

```js
let newRecords = records.map(r => {
    const date = moment(r.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').valueOf());
    return {...r, date}; // using spread operator just to get a new reference of the object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let newRecords = records.map(r => ({...r, date: moment(r.date, 'DD/MM/YYYY').valueOf()}));
```

Comment: I will mark the first answer as correct, because it was was the first to be posted. But I like this even more because it's a little cleaner to me eyes. I didn't think about using the spread operator. Nice one!